# Sencha Touch 2: Simulating different profiles (phone/tablet) on Desktop OS (Linux/Windows)

Tags: sencha-touch-2

I am learning Sench Touch 2. I figured if I want my app to be "responsive" to phone vs tablet platforms, I can use [Profiles](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/guide/profiles).

```
Ext.define('Mail.profile.Phone', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.Profile',

    config: {
        name: 'Phone',
        views: ['Main']
    },

    isActive: function() {
        return Ext.os.is.Phone;
    },

    launch: function() {
        Ext.create('Mail.view.phone.Main');
    }
});
```

I am developing on Arch Linux with Chromium. I installed installed user agent switchers to fake running on a tablet/phone OS, but the profiles doesn't appear to change anything. I added `console.log()` in the launch function

I wonder if I am using Profiles for the right thing? For example, I may want my app to display a list and a details view on tablets, and the list, animating to the details view 
on a phone. If so, do I need a real tablet/phone just to test this profiles?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can append `deviceType=Phone` or `deviceType=Tablet` to simulate these different device types.

Example here:

http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/touch/examples/production/kitchensink/index.html?deviceType=Phone

Answer (score 0):

I usually just change the "isActive" function in the Tablet and Phone profiles in order to achieve this. For example, if I want to test the Phone profile on my laptop, I just change it like this:

```
isActive: function() {
    return !Ext.os.is.Phone;
}
```

that is the exact opposite of what it should be. This is in fact the function I use in my Tablet profile.